# ItemSend Event for Appointment Outlook Addin throwing manifest validation error

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to have an on send handler assigned to a function within an Outlook addin for an Appointment. I strictly follow the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows), but I'm getting an error on the manifest validation

```
Error #1: 
Mailbox add-in containing ItemSend event is invalid.: Mailbox add-in containing ItemSend event is invalid.
  - Details: Mailbox add-in manifest contains ItemSend event in VersionOverrides which is not allowed.
```

My manifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>90992a37-6ac0-4e31-8f4d-c35d61ac033b</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>CKT (dev)</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Sync events with CKT Portal (dev)"/>
  
  <Description DefaultValue="Sync events of Outlook with CKT portal (dev)"/>
  
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org/addins/outlook/ckt.gif"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org/addins/outlook/ckt-128x128.gif"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org"/>

  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.8"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org/addins/outlook/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>

  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">

      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.8">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>

      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="apptReadDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton2">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton2.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton2.Label" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton2.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
    
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org/addins/outlook/ckt.gif"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org/addins/outlook/ckt-32x32.gif"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org/addins/outlook/ckt-80x80.gif"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://ckt-d.internal.epo.org/addins/outlook/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="CKT Add-in (dev)"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="CKT (dev)"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton2.Label" DefaultValue="CKT (dev)"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Sync Outllook events with CKT as Organizer (dev)"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton2.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Sync Outllook events with CKT as Attendee (dev)"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>

    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you specify the Outlook Version and OS where you are getting this error? We have tried the same manifest on OWA and Outlook Mac, it installs fine.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT the Outlook version is `Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14326.20702) 32-bit ` and OS is Windows 10. But the error is being triggered by the script command [`office-addin-manifest validate`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/tree/master/packages/office-addin-manifest)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I already submitted an issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/issues/613

Comment: Just to be clear, the add-in installs fine on Exchange, but just the manifest validator is returning an error?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT exactly, the addin install correctly but the validator is throwing an error. The validator docs never mention it is applicable only to the store.

Comment: Do you get the same errors with [smart alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough) that are allowed to be published to the store?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira We have updated the documentation accordingly. Kindly refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest

Answer (score 0):

- Our documentation is updated regarding office store validation with
  office-addin-manifest script. Please check here:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest#validate-your-manifest-with-office-addin-manifest
- Add-ins with On-Send events are not allowed on the add-in store. They can only be installed by the organization admin or manually.

Comment: I am installing it manually and it will be installed by the admin. Are you saying `office-addin-manifest validate` is only applicable to add-in store? The [docs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/tree/master/packages/office-addin-manifest) don't mention that the script is only applicable to the add-in store.

Comment: I would expect the `office-addin-manifest validate` to validate the syntax of ` <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">` and not just throw the error because the Office store doesn't support it. Hopefully @JoãoPimentelFerreira will not mark it as the answer, as this may mislead someone else who is puzzled by the same question. I am downgrading the answer, because it's irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, I also think the answer posted is irrelevant to the question. As I understand, the manifest validation process and publishing to the store are different things/actions not related to each other.